# Prevent certain objects from being added to a ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I was reading Eric Lippert blog about [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/). Interesting read, but I found certain parts hard to understand (not the authors fault, I'm only a beginner in OOP).

He presents the problem of two character types within a game, a Wizard and a Warrior, and the rules are:

- A warrior can only use a sword.
- A wizard can only use a staff

In the blog, he uses a `getter`/`setter` in the first part to handle the weapon for the character, but let's change it to an inventory system. So, we have an `abstract class` called Player with a list of items(`ArrayList`).

```
interface Weapon {
  attack(Enemy enemy);
}

public class Staff implements Weapon {} 

public abstract class Player {
    private List<Weapon> weaponInventory;

    //left out constructor and other methods to keep it on point

    abstract void add(Weapon add)
}
```

and use it like so:

```
public class Wizard extends Player {

   @Override
   public void add(Weapon add){
      //code to add weapon;
   }
}
```

How would you structure the add method to enforce the rule that a Wizard can only use a staff? I thought of calling `getClass()` or `getType()` on weapon but those are considered bad practice.

The best answer I could come up with was have a `String` variable called type, and a `getter` in the Weapon `interface`. During object construction, set the type to sword or staff. However, this doesn't really help, as you could create a sword object, pass in staff as the type, and use it.

How would you prevent a sword from being added to the wizards inventory?

Comment: It highly depends on your design.  If you want the checking be done in compile time, then generics as suggested in one of the answer can help.  However, in more realistic design, you seldom explicit give a `Staff` to a `Wizard`.  Instead, you give a `Weapon` to a `Player`.  So the checking gotta be done in runtime, and generics won't help here.  So it is hard to give you answer without knowing your design

Comment: @AdrianShum - Suppose runtime

Comment: Just had aquick glance on the article, author is thinking of compile-time though...

Comment: @AdrianShum - and doesn't like the use of generics in this situation. For my problem, I would like to know how, at run time to prevent a Wizard from adding a Sword to the inventory. He uses a getter/setter, but realistically you'll use an inventory like system(List, Dictionary, etc)

Comment: the idea is similar: you don't want to expose Player internal (e.g. `List<Weapon>`).  Provides methods to add/remove/navigate inventory of player.  For "how to check", it depends on design.  You may design some kind of "weapon classes" and each weapons is under one or more classes.  Each player declare its supported weapon classes.  When using the "inventory access methods" (e.g. `addWeapon(Weapon)`, do the checking in the method.

Comment: @AdrianShum - Would this mean overriding the equals method, which compares each weapon on String type? How would you implement your suggestion?

Comment: No. equals() is not for such purpose

Comment: Provide an example, how would you do it?

Comment: as I said, it is meaningless without the context of purpose of design.  I may simply have an enum to represent weapon class, each weapon we can get the weaponClass from it.  In Player, I may have a set of supported weapon class, so when people call add(Weapon), I do `if (!supportedWeaponClass.contains(weapon.getWeaponClass())) { return false;}`.  There are too too too many possibilities.  Worthless to go deeper discussion without knowing the purpose of design (simply saying "not adding weapon not supported by player" is too vague)

Comment: @AdrianShum - Doesn't this present a problem of putting too much trust in the client? What's to stop them from placing a WeaponType.Staff within the Sword constructor? Unless you do it yourself, i.e client doesn't set it, you do it privately in the constructor.

Comment: As I said, it depends on your design!!! If you have a class to represent a Sword, you shouldn't allow the caller to provide you the WeaponType.  The constructor internally should set it.  e.g.  `class Katana { public Katana() { super(WeaponType.SWORDS);} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following. Note: in the `Player` class, the weapons can be of any type. However each sub-class of player has its own specific `add()`. So while this approach enforces the required rules, it loses a little generality.

```
public class Staff implements Weapon {} 
public class Sword implements Weapon {} 

public abstract class Player {
    private List<Weapon> weaponInventory;
    protected final void addWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
         weaponInventory.add(weapon)
    }
 }

 public class Wizard extends Player {
     public void add(Staff staff) {
         addWeapon(staff);
     }
 }

 public class Warrior extends Player {
     public void add(Sword sword) {
         addWeapon(sword);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

> How would you structure the add method to enforce the rule that a Wizard can only use a staff?

Either you didn't read the whole series, or you didn't understand its central message.  The entire point of that series of articles is to express that **there is no good way to structure a method that enforces a restriction on the relationship between subclasses**.

This is simply a fact about subclass-based OOP; there are some things it does not model well, and this is one of them.  A fundamental principle of many OOP type systems, including that of Java and C#, is Liskov's: that you can *always* use an instance of a subclass where an instance of a superclass is needed. That makes modeling restrictions in the type system difficult.

In the last part of the series I give the best solution that I know of: model *the rules of the simulation as objects themselves*, and have a rule enforcer class that gives the user feedback when they attempt to violate a rule. Don't make the type system try to solve your business problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **generics**:

`Weapon` and `Staff` classes remain the same:

```
public interface Weapon {
   void attack(Enemy enemy);
}

public class Staff implements Weapon {

   @Override
   public void attack(Enemy enemy) {
    //Do ur attacking. :)
   }

}
```

The `Player` class has a **generic type**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Player<T extends Weapon> {
    protected List<T> weaponInventory = new ArrayList<>();//Made protected so Wizard can access it.

    public abstract void add(T weapon);

}
```

And the `Wizard` class extends `Player<Staff>` (NOT just `Player`):

```
public class Wizard extends Player<Staff> {

    @Override
    public void add(Staff weapon) {
        // Add the staff to the list declared in Player
        weaponInventory.add(weapon);
    }

}
```

### Explanation:

The `T` in `Player<T>` is the type of weapon that you want the player to use.

When you extend `Player<Staff>` in the `Wizard` class, you're saying that you want `Wizard` to be a `Player` that only uses `Staff`s. This way, the `Wizard`'s `weaponInventory` list will contain only `Staff`s.

When you add the `Warrior` class, it would extend `Player<Sword>`, which would make its `weaponInventory` only take `Sword`s.

By the way, I instantiated `weaponInventory` in the above code and implemented the `add` method in `Wizard`.